# How can you prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{100}}{1.01^x} = 0$ using definition of limit?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

How can you prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{100}}{1.01^x} = 0$ Using the definition of a limit?

I have been dabbling with this problem, and I am struggling to find an answer. There seem to be limited online resources on this type of problem. The common proof is to say that exponentials grow faster than polynomials, but how would you solve it using the definition?

By defintion:

If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = A$. Then for every possible $\epsilon > 0$ there must exist a $ k > 0$ such that
$| f(x) - A   | < \epsilon$ if $x > k$.

So I have  to find some function for the value of $k$ based on $\epsilon$ to prove the limit. I have tried:

$\bigg| \frac{x^{100}}{1.01^x} - 0  \bigg | < \epsilon$


$ \frac{x^{100}}{1.01^x}  < \epsilon$


$ \log {\frac{x^{100}}{1.01^x}}  < \log\epsilon$


$ 100*\log{x} - x*\log{1.01}  < \log\epsilon$

---

Now this is the part where I get stuck. I have tried to put in values for $x$, like $x=e$ the way blackpenredpen does: https://youtu.be/4pRMej3DnEM?t=512 and the continuing until I get x on the left side. This however seems to lead nowhere.

How would one solve this using the formal defintion?

Comment: First step can be to show that $\frac{x}{(\sqrt[100]{1.01})^x}\to 0$ and then multiply  100 times.

Comment: Second step, for $(a>1)$ can be $\frac{n}{a^n}=\frac{n}{(1+(a-1))^n}< \frac{n}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}(a-1)^2}\to 0$. And now you need only to go to real variable.

Comment: I'd change the title to "How can you prove that.." rather than "Can you prove that..". That it is possible to prove this using the definition is obvious, because the theorem you mention about exponentials growing faster than polynomials is proven using the definition, or else using other theorems which are themselves proved from the definitions, so unraveling the steps of the proof will give you a proof from the definition. (This is true in general for any result in mathematics.)

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with the function directly could be hard. Here is a way you can approach this. Ideally, you want

$$ \frac{x^{100}}{1.01^x}\leq \frac{1}{x}$$

Because if that is the case, then you can show that for $x\geq 1/\epsilon$

$$ \left|\frac{x^{100}}{1.01^x}\right|\leq \frac{1}{x} \leq \epsilon$$

Now, when is it the case that $ \frac{x^{100}}{1.01^x}\leq \frac{1}{x}$? Can you verify that this holds for sufficiently large $x$, say $x\geq 10^{10}$? If so, then for $k\geq \max(10^{10}, \frac{1}{\epsilon})$, we have

$$ \left|\frac{x^{100}}{1.01^x}\right|\leq \frac{1}{x} \leq \epsilon$$

And you're done.

Comment: It is much easier if instead of 118592 you take some nicer value, such as $10^{10}$.

Comment: @Freshman'sDream edited

Answer (score 0):

These all come down
to the fact that
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}
\to 0
$
as
$x \to \infty$.

More precisely,
for any $c > 0$,
there is an $x(c)$
such that
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}
\lt c
$ for
$x > x(c)
$.

If
$f(x)
=\dfrac{x^a}{b^x}
$
where
$a > 0, b>1$
then

$\begin{array}\\
g(x)
&=\ln(f(x))\\
&=a\ln(x)-x\ln(b)\\
&=ax(\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}-\dfrac{\ln(b)}{a})\\
\end{array}
$

Once
$x > x(\dfrac{\ln(b)}{2a})
$,
$g(x)
=ax(\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}-\dfrac{\ln(b)}{a})
\lt ax(\dfrac{\ln(b)}{2a}-\dfrac{\ln(b)}{a})
= -x\dfrac{\ln(b)}{2}
$
so
$g(x) \to -\infty$
as $x \to \infty$
so
$f(x)
=e^{g(x)}
\to 0
$.